# Check conditions to concat value in dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe.

| ID | B. | C. | D. | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | b1_main | null | d_value | e_value |
| 2. | b2_main | null | null | e_value |

The logic that I would want to apply concat value in B column to either value in C, D or E column. However, C will always take the first priority to concat with value in B column, if value in C column is null then it will only proceed to concat value in D column and proceed to E column if value in D column is also null.

**Desired Output**

| ID | B. | C. | D. | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | b1_main, d_value | null | d_value | e_value |
| 2. | b2_main, e_value | null | null | e_value |

The code that i tried is below however it will concat all the values in C,D and E and remove null value.

```
df['B'] = pb6_branded[['B','C', 'D', 'E']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use back filling missing values by columns `'C', 'D', 'E'` and select first column (here `C`) and add to `B` column:

```
df = df.replace('null', np.nan)
df['B'] = df['B'] + ', ' + df[['C', 'D', 'E']].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
#selecting by colum name
#df['B'] = df['B'] + ', ' + df[['C', 'D', 'E']].bfill(axis=1)['C']
print (df)
    ID                 B   C        D        E
0  1.0  b1_main, d_value NaN  d_value  e_value
1  2.0  b2_main, e_value NaN      NaN  e_value
```

If possible all `C, D, E` filled by empty values, is possible use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df = df.replace('null', np.nan)
s = df[['C', 'D', 'E']].bfill(axis=1)['C']
df['B'] = df['B'].str.cat(s, na_rep='', sep=', ').str.strip(' ,')
```